# Click event in for each loop fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `.each` loop like this:

```
$('.form-base-subscriptions input').each(function (index, value) {
    var uniqueId = $(this).attr('id'),
        uniqueId = uniqueId.substring(uniqueId.lastIndexOf('_')),
        $parent = $(this).parent(),
        $content = $parent.html();
        $content = $content.split('~'),
        input = $content[0],
        amount = $content[4],

var $toggle = $parent.find('.form-toggle'),
    $checkbox = $toggle.find('input');

    $toggle.on('click', function () {
        $('.form-base-subscriptions .form-toggle').removeClass('active');
        $('.form-base-subscriptions input').prop('checked', false);
        $toggle.addClass('active');
        $checkbox.prop('checked', true);

            var currentId = $(this).attr("id");

            if (currentId == "toggle_151" || currentId == "toggle_170") {
                amount = '1.50';
            } else {
                console.log('check');
                amount = '0';
            }

            $('#toggle_153 input').attr('data-amount', amount);
            $('#toggle_153 span').html(amount);

        //updateWellnessPrice();
        updateSubscriptionAmount();
    });
```

How to I trigger this `onCLick event` only once per click? Now it is fired twice per click.

Comment: move the click event out of the `.each` loop. Right now you're registering the click event multiple times because of the loop.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you seem to be dropping variables in the global scope due to a rogue `;` (or more likely, due to rogue `,`'s and you do not declare all variables at the top).

Comment: Need to see the relevant html - specifically, is there one `.form-toggle` (as the name and error imply) or one per input (as the code implies).  If there's only one, you want to ensure `$toggle.on('click'` is only called once.

Comment: Separately: within the click handler, use 'this' rather than a variable declared outside the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize event after the loop

```
var $toggle = '';
  $('.form-base-subscriptions input').each(function (index, value) {
    var uniqueId = $(this).attr('id'),
        uniqueId = uniqueId.substring(uniqueId.lastIndexOf('_')),
        $parent = $(this).parent(),
        $content = $parent.html();
        $content = $content.split('~'),
        input = $content[0],
        amount = $content[4],

   $toggle = $parent.find('.form-toggle'),
    $checkbox = $toggle.find('input');
});

$toggle.on('click', function () {
            $('.form-base-subscriptions .form-toggle').removeClass('active');
            $('.form-base-subscriptions input').prop('checked', false);
            $toggle.addClass('active');
            $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
            updateWellnessPrice();
            updateSubscriptionAmount();
        });
```

Comment: Initialize event after the loop and declare $toggle and $checkbox globally

Comment: why should I set that variables gloablly?

Comment: if you declare $toggle inside the loop then scope of the variable will be inside the loop, here i have registering event outside the loop so $toggle scope will be available outside the loop if you declare outside (it need not to be global but declare outside the loop).

Comment: you are registering the event for a class so registering only once is enough .i.e outside the loop. if you register inside loop it will register event multiple times and fire multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Put a class to all relevant elements and add an event listener for this class:

HTML

```
<div id="toggle_n" class="myElem"> .. </div>
...
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.myElem', function() {
   // Do your stuff here ..
});
```